# Getting MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume while installing stable RabbitMQ in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

I am getting below error while doing the installation of RabbitMQ through helm install.

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "config-volume" : couldn't
>   propagate object  cache: timed out waiting for the condition

Below is the details of kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.2", GitCommit:"17c77c7898218073f14c8d573582e8d2313dc740", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-24T06:54:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Pl
atform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.2", GitCommit:"81753b10df112992bf51bbc2c2f85208aad78335", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-27T09:10:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Pla
tform:"linux/amd64"}
```

And below is the command I used to install stable rabbitmq.

```
helm install --name coa-rabbitmq --set rabbitmq.username=#Username#,rabbitmq.password=#Password#,rabbitmq.erlangCookie=#Cookie#,livenessProbe.periodSeconds=120,readinessProbe.periodSeconds=120 stable/rabbitmq
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prerequisites
Kubernetes 1.8+
PV provisioner support in the underlying infrastructure

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan: Couldn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: please see the chart repo and the documnetation , it has some pre-reqs

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me. Looks like it's an issue related to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70044) in this case it can't mount the ConfigMap volume where the rabbitmq config is: the [`config-volume`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/rabbitmq/templates/statefulset.yaml#L200). It may also be the case that something is preventing mounting volumes on your nodes (process, file descriptor, etc).

You didn't specify where you are running this, but you can try bouncing your node components: kubelet, docker, and ultimately your node. Keep in mind that all other containers running on the node will restart somewhere again in the cluster.

**Edit:**

There was a mismatch between kubectl client, kubectl version and kubeadm version.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I checked further logs in "sudo journalctl -ru kubelet" and got this error. Nov 06 01:01:06 server-01 kubelet[507]: E1106 01:01:06.571565     507 reflector.go:134] object-"foundation"/"default-token-t8292": Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:node:server-01" cannot list secrets in the namespace "default": can only get individual resources of this type.

Comment: Now I am getting same error for different pods. So issue is not with rabbitmq but with kubernetes. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the issue is fixed now. There was a mismatch between kubectl client, kubectl version and kubeadm version. I have updated it to match and it is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome! Added an edit section to the answer